# Recognize from where Intent was sent

Tags: android, android-intent

I use a barcode scanner to scan some codes. To do that I call intent for scan action in barcode scanner.

Problem is I would like to send it from 2 different methods in my main activity for different purpose (different code type scans). Since I have only one answer with `onActivityResult()` how can I differentiate where the Intent call started?

Can I use some flag or tag or anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide a `requestCode` when starting an activity. This will then get provided back when overriding `onActivityResult`. In this way you can tell the requests apart.

```
private static final int METHOD_1_ID = 1;
private static final int METHOD_2_ID = 2;

private void sendIntentFromMethod2(){
    startActivityForResult(yourIntent, METHOD_2_ID);
}

private void sendIntentFromMethod1(){
    startActivityForResult(yourIntent, METHOD_1_ID);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   if (requestCode == METHOD_1_ID){
        // ...
   }else if(requestCode == METHOD_2_ID){
        // ... 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest methods would be passing for example int extra within intent, from activity A, pass 1,from activity B pass 2. Then use get extra and read the number, now you know which activity does this intent originate from. There are of course more sophisticated methods, but this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

When sending an Intent use this

```
Intent.putExtra("caller", caller_id)
```

When receiveing intent use

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id = extras.getInt("caller");
```

And before calling setResult

```
intent.puInt("phrase", id);
```

In onActivityResult use

```
Bundle  extras =  intent.getExtras();
int id = extras.getId( "selection" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start a activity to sacn barcode like this

```
 startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

**then from two different method, change your call like this**

//From first method

```
  startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

//From second method

```
 startActivityForResult(intent,2);
```

then

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if(requestCode==1)
{
//This is result for 1st method
}
   else if(requestCode==2)
{
//This is result for 2st method
}
```

}

***EDIT: Ah, giZm0's answer is easier!***